# Parallel decomposition of 2D grid with minimal communication

Tags: parallel-computing

Consider an $M\times N$ grid with periodicity in both dimensions upon which I want to do some local stencil-like computations using distributed-memory parallelism (MPI). I have two options for decomposing this problem:

(1) split the grid along one dimension so that each of the $P$ processes gets about $M/P\times N$ or $M\times N/P$ grid points, or

(2) divide the grid in both dimensions so that each process gets a rectangle of roughly $(M\times N)/\sqrt{P}$ grid points.

Obviously, approach (2) has a much lower communication bound than (1), but for rectangular grids of arbitrary size on arbitrary numbers of processes, finding a partitioning in 2D that balances the load seems difficult. I cannot restrict myself to allowing only $P=4^n$.

What is the state of the art in terms of these arbitrary 2D decompositions?

Answer (score 7):

The basic approach that I am using is *weighted orthogonal recursive bisection* (weighted ORB).

(which is usually applied to unstructured meshes or N-body simulations; however, it is still naturally applied to grids in $d$-dimensions)

Say (for example), you have a $N^x_0=100\times N^y_0=45$ rectangular grid that has $N^x_0*N^y_0=N_0=4500$ and you want to distribute it among $P=5$ processors. Here, $N_0$ stands for the total number of grid points at the $0$th partitioning level. The numbers are definitely arbitrary but should be illustrative enough.

Set initial weight at the $0$th partitioning level as $W_0=P=5$.
We will partition, until $W_\ell=1$ for each partition.

**First partitioning level ($100\times 45$)**:

1. Determine the largest dimension that we are going to cut along: $x$.
2. Determine weights and number of grid points for the left and right parts.

*Left part **00***:

$$
W_{00}=\left\lfloor{\frac{W_{0}}{2}}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor{\frac{5}{2}}\right\rfloor=2\\
\tilde{N}_{00}=N_{0}\frac{W_{00}}{W_{0}}=4500\frac{2}{5}=1800
$$

*Right part **01***:

$$
W_{01}=\left\lceil{\frac{W_{0}}{2}}\right\rceil=\left\lceil{\frac{5}{2}}\right\rceil=3\\
\tilde{N}_{01}=N_{0}\frac{W_{01}}{W_{0}}=4500\frac{3}{5}=2700
$$

3. Now, cut along the $y$ dimension at $n^x_{01}=1800/45=40$.

Resulting in **00**th partition being $40\times45$ (starting at $n^x_{00}=0$) and **01**th partitioning being $60\times 45$ (starting at $n^x_{01}=40$).

Since both $W_{00}, W_{01}>1$, the partitioning will continue on both left and right sides.

Note, $\tilde{N}_{\ell}$ is the estimated number of grid points in the partitioning before the cut is done. Actual ${N}_{\ell}$ is very close to $\tilde{N}_{\ell}$, but depends on the grid shape (and its dimensions being even or odd - *since bisection is being used*).

**Second partitioning level for *00* ($40\times45$):**

1. Determine the largest dimension to cut along: now $y$
2. Determine weights and number of grid points for the left and right parts.

*Left part **000***:

$$
W_{000}=\left\lfloor{\frac{W_{00}}{2}}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor{\frac{2}{2}}\right\rfloor=1\\
\tilde{N}_{000}=N_{00}\frac{W_{000}}{W_{00}}=1800\frac{1}{2}=900
$$

*Right part **000***:

$$
W_{001}=\left\lceil{\frac{W_{00}}{2}}\right\rceil=\left\lceil{\frac{2}{2}}\right\rceil=1\\
\tilde{N}_{001}=N_{00}\frac{W_{001}}{W_{00}}=1800\frac{1}{2}=900
$$

3. Now cut along the $y$ dimension at $n^y_{001}=\lfloor900/40\rfloor=22$

Resulting in **000**th partitioning being $40\times 22$ (starting at $n^x_{000}=0$) and **001**th partitioning being also $40\times 23$ (starting at $n^x_{001}=22$).

Since both $W_{000}, W_{001}=1$, the partitioning on this branch tree stops.

Note, in this step $\hat{N}_{00}=900$ is different from the actual $N_{00}=880$.

**Second partitioning level for *01* ($60\times45$):**

1. Determine the largest dimension to cut along: $x$
2. Determine weights and number of grid points for the left and right parts.

*Left part **010***:

$$
W_{010}=\left\lfloor{\frac{W_{01}}{2}}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor{\frac{3}{2}}\right\rfloor=1\\
\tilde{N}_{010}=N_{01}\frac{W_{010}}{W_{01}}=2700\frac{1}{3}=900
$$

*Right part **011***:

$$
W_{011}=\left\lceil{\frac{W_{01}}{2}}\right\rceil=\left\lceil{\frac{3}{2}}\right\rceil=2\\
\tilde{N}_{011}=N_{01}\frac{W_{011}}{W_{01}}=2700\frac{2}{3}=1800
$$

3. Now cut along the $x$ dimension at $n^x_{011}=900/45+40=60$

Resulting in **010**th partitioning being $20\times 45$ (starting at $n^x_{010}=n^x_{01}=40$) and **011**th partitioning being $40\times 45$ (starting at $n^x_{011}=60$).

Since $W_{010}=1$, the partitioning of this branch is finished; however, the right branch has to go to the third level as $W_{011}=2>1$.

**Third partitioning level for *011* ($40\times45$):**

1. Determine the largest dimension to cut along: $y$
2. Determine weights and number of grid points for the left and right parts.

*Left part **0110***:

$$
W_{0110}=\left\lfloor{\frac{W_{011}}{2}}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor{\frac{2}{2}}\right\rfloor=1\\
\tilde{N}_{0110}=N_{011}\frac{W_{0110}}{W_{011}}=1800\frac{1}{2}=900
$$

*Right part **0111***:

$$
W_{0111}=\left\lceil{\frac{W_{011}}{2}}\right\rceil=\left\lceil{\frac{2}{2}}\right\rceil=1\\
\tilde{N}_{0111}=N_{011}\frac{W_{0111}}{W_{011}}=1800\frac{1}{2}=900
$$

3. Now cut along the $y$ dimension at $n^y_{0111}=\lfloor900/40\rfloor=22$

Resulting in **0110**th partitioning being $40\times 22$ and **0111**th partitioning being $40\times 23$.

Alltogether, we have 5 leaf partitinings:

1. $N_{000}=880$ corresponding to processor with id $000_2=0$ (binary $\to$ dec)
2. $N_{001}=920$ corresponding to processor with id $001_2=1$
3. $N_{010}=900$ corresponding to processor with id $010_2=2$
4. $N_{0110}=880$ corresponding to processor with id $0110_2=6$
5. $N_{0111}=920$ corresponding to processor with id $0111_2=7$

Rearranging (renumbering) of the processor IDs is required to get to $0\ldots P-1$

with the final partitioning visualized:

[image: Partitioning visualization for 5 processors]

The total length of the boundaries between the partitionings is $40+45+45+40=170$ which is smaller than $45*4=180$ in case of simple partitioning along one largest dimension.

One of the references that (as far as I know) presented this method is:

- [J. K. Salmon, *Parallel hierarchical N-body methods*, Ph.D. Thesis, Caltech, 1992.](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=145731)

To balance the load even more (920 vs 880), one can assign half of the grid points on the 22/23 border to the left (**000**) and the other half to the right (**001**). The case for **0110** and **0111** is handled the same way. That introduces a little bit more complicated borders (with certain consequences).

[image: Partitioning visualization for 5 processors also using border-balancing]

Comment: Do you have any (pseudo)code which implements this partitioning?

Comment: @nluigi, not in the form I can share. That's why I tried to do a very detailed description, which is pretty much an "unwrapped" pseudocode for a representative example.